# Move data from one table to another in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

**Similar question may have been asked but not exactly the same.**

I need a simple solution for my sqlite database moving datas from one table to another with matching columns and the new table should have the maximum of transid +1.

For example: In my `tblsales_temp` table, I have fields: `transid, transdate, amount,status` and in my tblsales table, I have same fields: `transid,transdate,amount,status`
So, I want to move the data from tblsales_temp to tblsales but the transid in tblsales should be maximum of transid from tblsales +1.

How can this be done?

Comment: If in `tblsales` you have transIDs from 1 to 10, do you want all the inserted rows to get id=11, or start from 11 (and get 11, 12, ..., 20, ...)?

Comment: I want the inserted row to get id=11

thnx =)

Comment: All of them to get id=11? Isn't the `transid` the primary key?

Comment: not all of them, like 11,12,13...
yes, its the primary key

Comment: OK, then my answer will work.

Comment: thank you very much. and is it possible to select the maxid after inserting in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
INSERT INTO tblsales
  (transid, transdate, amount, status)
SELECT 
  t.transid + i.maxid,                    -- or just "i.maxid",
  t.transdate, t.amount, t.status         -- it's not clear what you want
FROM tblsales_temp AS t
  CROSS JOIN 
    ( SELECT MAX(transid) AS maxid 
      FROM tbsales
    ) AS i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tblsales
(transid, transdate, amount, status)
SELECT MAX(transid) + 1, transdate, amount, status
FROM tblsales_temp
```

Comment: no, you just did the opposite. Datas from tblsales_temp should be inserted in tblsales and the transid should be max from tblsales not tblsales_temp, in your case(max from tblsales_temp)

Comment: @DesterDezzods - adjusted.